# Let $f:[0,1] \to R$ be continuous such that $|f(x)| \le \int_0^xf(t)dt$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to R$ be continuous such that $|f(x)| \le \int_0^xf(t)dt$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Then,

a. Such $f$ does not exist

b. $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

c. $f(x)=c$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and some constant $c$

d. None of the above is true.

What I've tried doing : 
$$
f(x) \le |f(x)| \le \int_0^xf(t)dt
$$
and hence 
$$
f(x)-\int_0^xf(t)dt \le 0
$$
Let $g(x)=f(x)-\int_0^xf(t)dt$
$$
g'(x)=f'(x)-f(x)
$$
I have no idea what to do now. Any hints?

Comment: Gronwall inequality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the derivative of $e^{-x}h(x)$ is $e^{-x}(h'(x)-h(x))$ for any differentiable function $h$. (Remember this trick whenever you see an expression of the form $h'(x)-h(x)$.) Here, that gives us

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\right)=e^{-x}\left(f(x)-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\right)$$

The right-hand side is $\le 0$ on $[0,1]$, because $f(x)-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\le|f(x)|-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$. So the function $e^{-x}\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ is non-increasing on $[0,1]$. And it takes the value $0$ at $x=0$, so it must be $\le 0$ on the whole of $[0,1]$. $e^{-x}$ is strictly positive, so we have $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt \le 0$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Hence $0\le|f(x)|\le\int_0^xf(t)\,dt \le 0$ on $[0,1]$, which gives immediately $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I have never seen that trick before in all my life.  Nice.

Comment: +1 Nice, i used this trick to prove that if $f$ is differentiable and $f = f'$ then $f(x) = c e^x$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.